# How to get SUM of values and add previous values in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like as below

[image]

Here i need to add one more column and that should be addition of credit limit and addl credit.
If any addl credit is available that total sum should be appeared for next records until there is any addl credit is added. i am expected the result as like below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with a window function.

```sql
Select *,
credit_limit + 
sum(credit_limit_added_on) over fill_na  as Total_credit
from yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable
window fill_na as (order by timestamp ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND current row)
```